# Mysql query returns no data with escaped \

Tags: mysql, escaping

I'm attempting to query our MSSQL database but I'm getting no data when there clearly is data there.

First I query

```
SELECT id, instruction_link FROM work_instructions WHERE instruction_link LIKE "%\\\\cots-sbs%";
```

Which returns 100+ lines. 
http://tinypic.com/r/ief8td/8
(sorry couldn't post as actual picture, don't have enough rep :(

However if I query

```
SELECT id, instruction_link FROM work_instructions WHERE instruction_link LIKE "%\\\\cots-sbs\\%";
```

http://tinypic.com/r/33ksw3q/8

I get no results with the 2nd query. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Seems pretty simple but I can't make any sense of it..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

> #### Note
>
> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “`\n`” to represent a newline character), you must double any “`\`” that you use in [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) strings. For example, to search for “`\n`”, specify it as “`\\n`”. To search for “`\`”, specify it as “`\\\\`”; this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

`\\%` is parsed as a *string* containing a literal backslash followed by a percentage character, which is then interpreted as a *pattern* containing only a literal percentage sign.